# iTextSharp 7 circular reference

Tags: itext

Is there a mechanism in iTextSharp 7 to avoid/detect circular references?
For instance, if somebody adds in code cell C to table T and by error adds back table T to cell C, the application goes in an endless loop and is shut down by the system. Do this in IIS, a computer restart is needed in order to make IIS run again. Is there a place to report a bug like this?

Comment: I've created an issue with number [DEVSIX-752](https://jira.itextsupport.com/browse/DEVSIX-752) in our closed ticketing system.

Comment: But, um, is it a library's responsibility to prevent this kind of behavior ? I mean, a Stack Overflow can only be prevented by the code that actually creates it - in this instance: your client code.

Comment: I agree, but still, it can be prevented. The code might be complex sometimes, it is easy to do a mistake, but the consequences are more than ending the task in the OS, sometimes.